# Как фильтровать количество товара у Торговых предложений в GetList?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет! Использую свой компонент для реализации каталога. Необходимо вывести товары и если у товара есть sku, тогда там реализуется отдельная логика, но это не так важно. Нужно отфильтровать товары, где количество на складе больше нуля. Если в фильтр просто добавить QUANTITY > 0, тогда все sku просто не будут выводиться, а если фильтровать после и найдутся товары с 0 количеством, то они обрежутся и на странице вместо 9 установленных элементов выведется например 6.

Вопрос как правильно это всё дело отфильтровать?

```
  private function getItems(int $iblockID, $sections = '') : array
        {
            $n = 0;
            $elementsCount = 9;
            $pagin = ($_GET['PAGE_ID']) ? $_GET['PAGE_ID'] : 1;  //Номер текущей пагинации
            $filter = array('IBLOCK_ID' => $iblockID, 'ACTIVE' => 'Y');
            if($sections) $filter['SECTION_CODE'] = $sections;
            $filter['>CATALOG_QUANTITY'] = 0;
    
            $items = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $filter, false, array('iNumPage' => $pagin, 'nPageSize' => $elementsCount),
            array('ID', 'NAME', 'PREVIEW_TEXT',
            'PREVIEW_PICTURE', 'SECTION_CODE', 'CATALOG_PRICE_1', 'QUANTITY', 'DETAIL_PAGE_URL', 'CATALOG_QUANTITY '));
    
            while($item = $items->GetNext())
            {
                $result[] = $item;
                $mxResult = \CCatalogSku::getOffersList($item['ID'], $iblockID, array('ACTIVE' => 'Y', '>QUANTITY' => 0), array('ID'));
                if($mxResult)
                {
                    $result[$n] = $item;
                    $result[$n]['SKU'] = 1;
                }
                else if($item['QUANTITY'] > 0) $result[$n] = $item;
            $n++;
            }
    
            $itemsCountAll = $itemsCountRound = $items->SelectedRowsCount();
            $countRound = $itemsCountAll / $elementsCount;
            if($itemsCountAll % $elementsCount === 0) $itemsCountRound = $countRound;
            elseif($itemsCountAll % $elementsCount > 0) $itemsCountRound = ceil($countRound);
    
            $this->itemsCountRound = $itemsCountRound;
            $this->itemsCountAll = $itemsCountAll;
    
            return $result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. В Битрикс нет такого механизма.

Comment: получайте то что нужно ручками ¯\_(ツ)_/¯